# Could not connect to broker URL after 5000 ms [JMS]

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I use Spring Integration 3.0.0 with Active MQ 5.11.1 it works without any problem. but I noticed that when I stop Active MQ, i get error in my logs every 5 seconds.
if you have an idea for this problem?

**Error :**

```
ERROR [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1] [DefaultMessageListenerContainer]  Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'topic' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: localhost. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Answer (score 2):

When the listener container loses the connection, it tries to reconnect every 5 seconds by default until the broker is running again.

You can configure the time and/or add an exponential back off. See `setRecoveryInterval` and `setBackOff`.

Or, call `stop()` on the container to stop the attempts.

Call `start()` to start again.

Comment: thnx for your answer, but this it's possible for "message-driven-channel"? because my problem is in message-driven adapter and not in outbound-channel-adapter

Comment: This applies to a message driven adapter or message driven channel. It's not relevant for an outbound adapter. I am not sure why you consider it a "problem". It's working as designed.